# ssh on multiple servers at the same time

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have to login into various servers using ssh parallely using a shell script.
It is a password less authentication. I have to login into 25 servers and restart a process which takes a lot of time. Hence i want to do the process in all the servers at the same time. My script goes like this:

```
while read line
do
ssh $line
------restart process-------
done < list.txt &
```

Here "list.txt" has the list of servers. I have used "&" to invoke new shell for each iteration and repeat the process for all servers. But the script is still executing the restart process for the servers in the list one after other. Its not executing the restart process at the same time. the server where script runs is bulit on bash whereas the 25 servers where the process has to be restarted are bulit on korn shell. Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in the script or parallel login using ssh is possible or not?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have other options rather than use the script. My suggestions will go to use an script done with fabric http://www.fabfile.org/ or use another tool like pssh https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/

Comment: @PerroVerd......Thanks for your answer.......pssh works for me

Comment: Have been using clusterssh for an interactive case. It can be used to type command into all hosts, or just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work using a `heredoc` - see [Wikipedia heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
while read line
do
   ssh $line <<'EOF' &
      command
      command
   EOF
done < list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You are backgrounding the main loop, not the ssh execution try with this

```
while read line
do
  ssh $line ---restart process--- &
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the restart process has many commands and  some if then else test conditions also. Can you tell where should i put the "&" symbol to background the entire process and proceed to the next iteration of the external while loop?

Comment: The easy way is to create another script restart_process.sh with all the commands needed and background it in the while loop